# Django 1.8 OperationalError: no such column:

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using django 1.8 and I'm having problems adding to my models.py. Currently it's:

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Company(models.Model):
    role = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True)
```

and it works perfectly fine but whenever I try to add to this and then run the server I get

> OperationalError: no such column [added element]

For example I added `founder = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)` and I ran the program and I got

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: companies_company.founder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run in your console this commands:

```
manage.py makemigrations app_name
manage.py migrate app_name
```

Every time when you change model in your app you should migrate changes to your db using makemigration and migrate commands. When you adding a new column to your db table you must add value of this column to all existing rows. You can do it by seting default value in your new field in your model. 
Or set values when run migrate command  ( django automatically propose this)
You can read about this in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)

Comment: What django print in console when you ran makemihration and migrate commands

Comment: The exact error is too long to post here but the important part at the end is "django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: companies_company.founder"

Comment: When you add new column you should set default value  to your field in model or set values for all existing rows in migrate command

Comment: What do you mean? How can I do that?

Comment: founder = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='something') or when you run manage.py migrate app_name django will show you message that you must set default values for existing raws and it run python console where you can do this

Comment: Maybe you should turn that into a answer to the question also maybe you can explain a but more.

Comment: I don't know what to set default to.

Comment: What should 'something' be?

Comment: You make something wrong, makemigrations can't throw this exception. Are you sure that you migrate correct app?

Comment: I am certain it is this app. it is  my only app.

Comment: 'Something' it default value which saved in your db. And if you already have data in your db(this data without your new column) it add new column and set this default value('something') to all existing data

Comment: How can I find this default value?

Comment: It bad solution but it's must work. Just drop your db and run manage.py syncdb again.

Comment: How do I drop my db? Btw thank you for helping thus far

Comment: You set default value when create field to your model. Your new field is charfield it seems that default value must be any string you want

Comment: What db you are using?

Comment: Simply delete file with you database. If you don't change settings.py it should be named as mydatabase.sqlite and placed in project root directory. And again run syncdb.

Comment: I too got the same error, and `makemigrations` , ` migrate` didn't work. I read the docs and I understand that, it should actually work. What can be the possible reason?

Answer (score 2):

This type of problem occurs when there are some operations on the model field in some other files such as `forms.py` or `views.py` other than `models.py` when you run `makemigrations`. If you read the traceback carefully you can figure it out from which file the problem is originating.

For example, if the traceback tells you some complaints in `forms.py` which may happen to use some of the model fields, just comment out the code that is working on the model fields and rerun `makemigrations` again. Hopefully it resolves the issue.

If it does, you can then remove the comments that you added before.

Answer (score 0):

You have to re sync the database using python manage.py makemigrations

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not optimal, but it worked for me doing that (and the default thing did not work):

1. delete all files apart from the **init**.py in migrations folder
2. delete the db.sqlite file
3. doing: `python manage.py runserver` (without this one previous to migrate, migrations, that did not work, I think it's linked to the views / templates calling tags, so has to run first)

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Answer (score -1):

I found that clearing all data with `python3 manage.py sqlflush` and then `python3 manage.py flush`

Then makemigrations, sqlmigrate, and then migrate

It will delete all data in the SQL database including users and objects